# Findbugs claims Activity.OnCreate has a synchronization issue. True?

Tags: android, android-activity, synchronization, findbugs

In my Activity.OnCreate I am setting up some android ImageViews. Findbugs is complaining about potential unsynchronized access - all other access is from other overridden Activity methods (or construction time), so this seems strange. Can I safely ignore this?

The Findbugs warning:

> Bug: Inconsistent synchronization of
>   com.voltup.powermax.Activity.mActionButton; locked 66% of time Pattern
>   id: IS2_INCONSISTENT_SYNC, type: IS, category: MT_CORRECTNESS
>
> The fields of this class appear to be accessed inconsistently with
>   respect to synchronization.  This bug report indicates that the bug
>   pattern detector judged that

Comment: To clarify, findbugs is claiming OnCreate() is not synchronized with the rest of the Activity methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complaining about which methods? Can you post the code? But probably, yes, you can ignore that.

Comment: Updated in main question. Example method is onActivityResult()

Comment: There really shouldn't be any need to make the normal activity callbacks synchronized. I would ignore findbugs.